# Is there an abstraction for the declare-update-return pattern?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, idioms, mutation

When writing iterative code with mutation in ruby, I often find myself following this pattern:

```
def build_x some_data
  x = [] # or x = {}
  some_data.each do |data|
    x.some_in_place_update! (... data ...)
  end
  x
end
```

(`x` often does not have the same shape as `some_data`, so a simple `map` will not do.)

Is there a more idiomatic or better way to write code that follows this pattern?

---

[edit] A real example:

```
def to_hierarchy stuff
  h = {}
  stuff.each do |thing|
    path = thing.uri.split("/").drop(4)
    sub_h = h
    path.each do |segment|
      sub_h[segment] ||= {}
      sub_h = sub_h[segment]
    end
    sub_h.merge!(
      data: thing.data,
    )
  end
  h
end
```

This begins with a flat list of `thing`s, which have related but distinct `uri`s. It transforms this flat list into a hierarchy, grouping related `thing`s that share the same `segment`s of a `uri`. This follows the pattern I described: initialize `h`, loop over some data and mutate `h` along the way, and then spit out `h` at the end.

[edit2] Another related example

```
def count_data obj
  i = if obj[:data] then 1 else 0
  obj.each do |k, v|
    i += count_statements v unless :data == k
  end
  i
end
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. `x = []` followed by `x.some_in_place_update!(data)` makes `some_in_place_update!` a method of `Array`, and its name implies it is modifying array `x` in-place (given an element of `some_data` as input) even though it is empty. Have you *really* patched `Array` with a new method? It would help a lot to know the sort of thing `some_in_place_update!` is doing.

Comment: can you please give use one or two examples of actual methods with that pattern?

Comment: @Borodin "in place update" was perhaps a bad way of describing what I actually meant. I was trying to convey the idea that object `x` was being mutated by that method invocation.

Comment: @DanBurton: Ah! You want `each_with_object`. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `to_hierarchy` example could be done with [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def to_hierarchy stuff
  stuff.each_with_object({}) do |thing, h|
    #...
  end
end
```

`each_with_object` passes the extra object to the block *and* returns that object when the iteration is done.

If you're more of a traditionalist, you could use [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
def to_hierarchy stuff
  stuff.inject({}) do |h, thing|
    #...
    h
  end
end
```

Note the block argument order change and that the block has to return `h` so that `inject` can feed it back into the next block invocation.

Your general example could be written as:

```
def build_x some_data
  some_data.each_with_object([]) do |data, x|
    x.some_in_place_update! (... data ...)
  end
end
```

or:

```
def build_x some_data
  some_data.inject({}) do |x, data|
    x.some_in_place_update! (... data ...)
    x
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah! You want `each_with_object`. Like this

```
def to_hierarchy stuff
  stuff.each_with_object({}) do |thing, h|
    path = thing.uri.split("/").drop(4)
    sub_h = h
    path.each do |segment|
      sub_h[segment] ||= {}
      sub_h = sub_h[segment]
    end
    sub_h.merge!(
        data: thing.data,
    )
  end
end
```